# How do you rotate a BoneAttachment3D during an animation?

Tags: camera, rotation, godot-4

I have a case where I want to rotate a bone that is otherwise controlled by an animation.

The bone is the head bone of a humanoid skeleton. I have attached a `BoneAttachment3D` to which is childed a `Camera3D`. This is because when the player is idling, I want the camera to be looking around per the animation.

When the player grabs the mouse and starts looking around, I want the head bone to rotate around the X-axis so the head and the camera can look up and down. The Y rotation turns the whole body, so it is not subject to the bone limiting rotation around that axis.

Can someone point out how to rotate the head bone around *just* the X-axis?